# Boostrap Vue Change Cell Text in B-table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

In a b-table, each cell in a column should have different text color. Not the background of the cell, but the actual text color. I am able to change the text color of the column header, but not the individual cell texts.

The b-table code:

```
<b-card title="Total">
  <b-table sticky-header="600px" hover :items="total" :fields="groupByFields"></b-table>
</b-card>
```

The fields where the column header color change is:

```
groupByFields: [
    {
      key: 'name',
      sortable: true,
    },
    {
      label: 'Total',
      key: 'count',
    },
    {
      key: 'interested',
      thStyle: { color: '#3eef33' },
      sortByFormatted: false,
      formatter: (value) => {
        const res = value;
        return (`($${res})`);
      },
    },
  ],
```

The `thStyle` color attribute changes the header text color, but not the text of values in the cells of that column. How would I match that color to the cell text (not background) of that column too?

Comment: there's a LOT of information in the [documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table) - surely there's something that will do what you want? hint: I think you'll want to use classes rather than inline styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example, using the `#cell()` slot:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: [],
    fields: [
      'id',
      { key: 'title', style: { fontStyle: 'italic' } },
      { key: 'price', style: { color: 'red', textAlign: 'right' } }
    ]
  }),
  mounted() {
    fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products')
     .then(_ => _.json())
     .then(_ => this.items = _.products);
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.22.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.22.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
    <template #cell()="{field, value}">
      <div :style="field.style" v-text="value" />
    </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```

If you only need to style a few columns, you might want to use appropriate `#cell({key})` slots.

Documentation [here](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#comp-ref-b-table-slots).

---

Probably the most common technique is to add classes to cells. It provides granular control over the applied styling, without sacrificing flexibility.

Comment: Thank you! It was the `#cell({key})` that I needed. I had been doing the regular `#cell()=` which wasnt grabbing the specific column